# How to order a linked collection with the Contentful GraphQL API

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, content-management-system, contentful

For the blog I'm working on I have a category page that lists all blogposts that are tagged with that category. Now I want to order those blogs by the `createdAt` date but I can't seem to find a solution how to order a linked collection with the Contentful GraphQL API.

The query currently looks like this:

```
query {
  categoryCollection(limit: 1, where: {slug: "aws"}) {
    items {
      linkedFrom {
        postCollection(limit: 6, skip: 0) {
          total
          items {
            title
            content
            createdAt
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can use the `order` parameter for the categoryCollection but not for the postCollection. Is there anything I'm missing with the GraphQL API or do I need to change my content model in Contentful to make this work?

Comment: if `postCollection` accepts some `orderBy` arg - check [API] docs, use playground (docs inside) !!!

Comment: @xadm That's the problem. `postCollection` only accepts an order arg if it's the top level of the query not when it is `linkedFrom`.

Comment: then simply not supported now (IDK, maybe with some model change) ... sort after fetching, inside react component <SomeLinkedFromListWithSorting data={unsortedData} limit=6 />` or sort before passing/rendering